# What font does TwentyTweleve use? (not as simple as it sounds)

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

This initially sounds like a silly question but Im baffled.

I downloaded and installed Wordpress with the default TwentyTwelve theme which looks great but I wanted to make a few tweaks.

So I went into style.css and changed the css for name of the blog

```
.site-header h1 a, .site-header h2 a
```

When I added

```
font-style:italic
```

the font and text changed completely.

I've attached a screenshot with an addition of font-size:80px just to make it a bit clearer to see.

Its exactly the same page, and the only difference is the italic line, but somehow it has changed?

I recognise the original is probably Open Sans, but what is the font when I make it italic (the second line) please?

I need some rep points to upload images but here is a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKdom.png

Seems trivial - but the main difference is the lowercase 'a' and 'f'

I've tried Firebug to try and work out what it is but all I can see is that its Open Sans??

Comment: Fonts on the web are complicated and frustrating, especially for graphics artists (at least for ours) but this is a pure HTML/CSS question and is therefore off-topic per the [faq]. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Italic font is still Open Sans, "a" and "f" are just designed to look like that in the italic version.

[Open Sans demo](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans)

Comment: AHH Thanks Natko - I hadnt imported all the available font weight styles available